# Finding the interval in which g is increasing

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f$ is a continuous function with a domain $[−3, 9]$ such that

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
3, & \text{if -3 $\leq$ x <0}\\
-x+3, & \text{if 0$\leq$ x $\leq$ 6}\\
-3, & \text{if 6< x $\le$ 9} 
\end{cases}$

If $g(x)=\int_{-2}^x{f(t)}dt$, on what interval is $g$ increasing?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $g'(x)=  f(x)$ now see where $g'(x)\geq 0 $